# Issuer not in URI format - ITfoxtec SAML 2.0

Tags: itfoxtec-identity-saml2

Multiple SAML Service Providers we tested are are using an Issuer which is not in an URI format this causes issues in the code where an URI is expected:

`Issuer = XmlDocument.DocumentElement[Schemas.Saml2Constants.Message.Issuer, Schemas.Saml2Constants.AssertionNamespace.OriginalString].GetValueOrNull<Uri>()`;

in `Saml2Request.cs`

for example: https://sptest.iamshowcase.com/

will have `<saml:Issuer>IAMShowcase</saml:Issuer>`

Do you know an easy fix for this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are right, the currently ITfoxtec Identity SAML 2.0 version only support an Issuer with a URI format. Furthermore, the same problem exists in relation to EntityID and AllowedAudienceUris.

Issuer, EntityID and AllowedAudienceUris support string values from version 3.1.0-beta3 https://github.com/ITfoxtec/ITfoxtec.Identity.Saml2/releases/tag/3.1.0-beta3. *Remark: This beta version also adds support for Azure Key Vault.*

Please let me know if the beta version works for you.

*** Update ***

[Version 4.0.0](https://github.com/ITfoxtec/ITfoxtec.Identity.Saml2/releases/tag/4.0.0) is released supporting Issuer, EntityID and AllowedAudienceUris as string values.

Comment: Thanks for the answer I will try out. Do you have a road map to publish a final version 3.1.0 ? Are there know issues in this beta ?

Comment: I plan to test the version a little further among other in https://foxids.com and await if anyone including you report problems. And then release the final version. There is no known issues.